# How to run system commands via python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want kill the process using a Python program in a Linux environment. i've used below code to kill the process but it doesn't work for me.

Can someone help me in this case?

Thanks in advance.

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.run("ps aux |grep python |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill");
```

I'm not getting any error while running above code also the command was not worked in the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: use may have to use it with `sp.run(..., shell=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some ways to run system commands via a python program:

#### Using the os module:

```
import os
os.system("ps aux |grep python |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill")
```

#### Using the subprocess module

```
import subprocess
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'python'], stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc3 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', "'{print $2}'"], stdin=proc2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc4 = subprocess.Popen(['xargs', 'kill'], stdin=proc3.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
proc2.stdout.close() # Allow proc2 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc3 exits.
proc3.stdout.close() # Allow proc3 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc4 exits.
out, err = proc4.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.system("ps aux |grep python |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill")`:

```
import os

os.system("ps aux |grep python |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill")
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: i've tried this also, but i dont know what is happening behind. still this is not killing the process, and its not thrown an error.

Comment: Check if it requires `sudo` permissions?
Try running it with, `sudo python <script_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **os module** you can simply run the system commands:

```
import  os

os.system("ps aux |grep python |awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill")
```